# Join number together in php - E.G. 2 + 2 = 22

Tags: php

I am making a website, so when you register, it sends you a confirmation email with a code. I have used this before, and I am wondering how to do this. I have four 1-9 random numbers, and I am wondering just how to join the numbers together to make a single one, or, if this isn't the proper way to do this, I would love to hear your thoughts.

Example

```
2 + 2 + 2 + 2 is 2222
```

> Thanks to all of you who solved my question. Concatenation. I am an idiot.

Comment: are you wanting a random key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in many way like using `.` or `,` and so on. But I prefer with simple concatenation using `.`  See more about concatenation at official site http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
$n1= 2;
$n2= 2;
$n3= 2;
$n4= 2;
echo $n1.$n2.$n3.$n4;
```

**Program Output**

```
2222
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/981727

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer ASAP

Comment: @Will OK . best of luck..:)

Answer (score -2):

I don't have an instance to test with but you could probably cast to string before using the add operator.

```
(string)2 + (string)2
```

If I am thinking correctly that should give you "22".

**Edit:** I was wrong and "+" is not interchangeable with string concatenation in PHP. the "." operator would be the correct one to use instead and would not require explicitly casting to string.

Comment: `+` is arithmetic plus. And values will be casted back to numbers. So, no, you're not thinking correctly.

Comment: fair enough. Hard to remember operator logic between php and other languages off hand.